# Can I get ingress live manifest information with ArgoCD CLI?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, argoproj, argocd

[image]

Can I get ingress live manifest information with ArgoCD CLI?

How can I get this information in this picture info?

Answer (score 2):

`argocd app manifests APPNAME [flags]`, the flag to use for live manifests is `--source live`

so if the app is called argocd, the command will be like this:
`argocd app manifests argocd --source live`

This will return all the manifests of the app and unfortunately there is no flag to do the filtering per resource. You could use something like https://github.com/mogensen/kubernetes-split-yaml or do your own yaml parsing.